# select in mysql where a certain row only has a count of 1

Tags: mysql

Im still a novice in mysql, only have had to use basic queries in my code until now. But I need the following right now. I have a database with rows: id, firstname, lastname, email, companyid.

I want to select all values where the companyid only has a count of one in the entire database. (some contacts share a company). Secondly I need to select all first created contacts for a company where a company has more then 1 entries in the database. Tried a bunch with group, distinct, but cant get this to work.

```
SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE (SELECT COUNT(companyid) FROM `contacts`) <2
```

Tried this but it is not correct (obviously).

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

First task:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM contacts c
JOIN (SELECT companyid, COUNT(*) c
      FROM contacts
      GROUP BY companyid
      HAVING c = 1) c1
ON c.companyid = c1.companyid
```

Second task:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM CONTACTS c
JOIN (SELECT companyid, MIN(created) mindate, COUNT(*) c
      FROM contacts
      GROUP BY companyid
      HAVING c > 1) c1
ON c.companyid = c1.companyid AND c.created = c1.mindate
```

To perform an UPDATE based on the first query:

```
UPDATE contacts c
JOIN (SELECT companyid, MIN(created) mindate, COUNT(*) c
      FROM contacts
      GROUP BY companyid
      HAVING c > 1) c1
ON c.companyid = c1.companyid AND c.created = c1.mindate
WHERE yourcode = 1
SET somecolumn = newvalue
```

Comment: Wow, this is great, also so quickly. I still have a lot to learn in Mysql I see. I couln't have thought of this code myself. Do you have any tips on places to start for expanding my general knowledge of mysql?

Comment: Sorry to ask so much but how do I change the first code to update all values of 1 column to a certain value where ( yourcode ) = true?

Comment: Added to the answer. I think you need to study up on SQL. You can't depend on free volunteers to do all your programming for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use HAVING clause :

```
SELECT companyid,COUNT(id) as cnt FROM `contacts` group by companyid having COUNT(ID)=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this would solve your problem but you can try this

```
SELECT *, COUNT(companyid) 
FROM CONTACTS
GROUP BY 1
HAVING COUNT(companyid) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.id, c.firstname, c.lastname, c.email, c.companyid
FROM contacts c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(id) as id FROM contacts GROUP BY companyid
) c2 ON c2.id = c.id
```

MIN(id) will select the first created (oldest) on companies where there are multiple contacts.
GROUP BY will ensure one row per companyid

Refence: http://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html